# Power Automate Flow - Trigger issue for solutioncomponent entity

Tags: power-automate, dataverse

I'm trying to create a flow that triggers when a `solutioncomponent` entity is added/modified or deleted (i.e. When you add an existing web resource to a custom solution) - screenshot added.

However, this never triggers, is there a restriction on using the `solutioncomponent` entity? How can I get the trigger working? (I could get the trigger working when I do for the `solution` entity).

Thanks

[image: Screenshot]